# Как решить проблему с запуском activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, recycleview

Есть activity с recyclView.

```
public class NotesActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements adapter.ItemTouchHelper.ItemTouchHelperListener{

public List<Notes> notesList;
private NotesHandler notesHandler;
private NotesAdapter notesAdapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.notes_activity);

    notesHandler = new NotesHandler(getApplicationContext());

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycle_view);

    prepareData();

    notesAdapter = new NotesAdapter(getApplicationContext(), notesList);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(notesAdapter);
```

В котором есть список элементов, по нажатию которых, получаю данные с элемента и открываю новое activity, использую для редактирования данных.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int pos = getAdapterPosition();
    if (pos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, CreateActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("id", pos);
        intent.putExtra("title", textViewTitle.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("text", textViewText.getText().toString());
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

В другом activity получаю эти данные.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.creature_activity);

    notesHandler = new NotesHandler(this);

    editSubject = findViewById(R.id.edit_subject);
    editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

    int id;
    String title;
    String text;

    id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");
    title = getIntent().getExtras().getString("title");
    text = getIntent().getExtras().getString("text");

    if (title != null && text != null){
        editSubject.setText(title);
        editText.setText(text);
    }

}
```

Но данное activity я еще использую для создания данных, где не нужно получать это вот, вышеописанное. 
Как быть? 
Ставить

```
try {

} catch (Exception e){

}
```

???

Comment: ну шлете ID равный , например -1 и делаете ветвление - если пришел id = -1 то пропускаете все вот это вот .. вышеописанное

Comment: или если при создании данных вообще не шлете интент, то просто проверяете его на null и тоже делаете ветвление

Comment: Дело в том, что при создании activity, он пытается получить id, все равно, если не смог получить, то вылетает:
id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");

Comment: `Intent i = getIntent(); if (i == null) ...создание... else .. редактирование..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("id")){
    id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");
    title = getIntent().getExtras().getString("title");
    text = getIntent().getExtras().getString("text");
}else{
   //что-то с id и другим.
}
```

Проверка есть ли в интенте extra с названием "id".